# How to embed a website in javascript without an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

**I am trying to make a Website that has IE and Opera compatibility.**

For Those browsers, iframes are not allowed. According to Opera Browser Wiki,

> "...Only normal HTML5 and JS is allowed on Opera Browser and IE, Therefore no iFrames are allowed on here"

I have a section of my website that is an iframe. Here is my code.

**Style.css**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap');
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#header{
  background: #711495;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #711495, #D63A85);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #9336b7, #D63A85);
background: linear-gradient(to top left, #711495, #d33a84);
  color:white;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
/*Info Colors*/
.white{color: white;}
.green{color: #21d900;}
.red{color:#f02222;}
.blue{color: lightskyblue;}
.black{color:#797979;}
/*End*/
td{
  width: 10%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
#left, #right {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border:solid;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding:10px;
  border-width: thin;
}
.Bordermap{
  border:solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-align: center;
}
.a{
  background-color: #3695f4;
  color: white;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left:2.25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.a:hover{
  background-color: #f79800;
}
.rajscape{
  background-color: none!important;
}
.hei{
  background-size: 50%;
}
.oddaout{
  background-color: none!important;
}
.nope_nothing_at_all{
  color: white;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
.ok{
  background-color: none!important;
}
#darK{
  background-color: black!important;  
}
.header-dark{
  background-color:#393939;
  
  color:white;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  
}
.dark{
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: #292929;
}
.full{
  background-color: #3695f4;
  color: white;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left:2.25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}
.margin-left{
  margin-left: 175px;
}
#top-link-area{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The New COVID-19 Tracker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-4436265437354189" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<style>
  #embeddev{
    margin: 30px;
  }
  .qwerty {
        font-family: 'Poppins', serif;
        color:white;
      }
  .sidebar { 
            height: 100%; 
            width: 0; 
            position: fixed; 
            /*Stays in place */ 
            background-color: #303630; 
            /*Grey*/ 
            overflow-x: hidden; 
      color:white;
      z-index: 12;
            /*for Disabling horizontal scroll */ 
        } 
        /* Position and style for the sidebar links */ 
        
        .sidebar a { 
            padding: 10px 10px 10px; 
            font-size: 25px; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            display: block; 
            transition: 0.3s; 
        } 
        /* the links change color when mouse hovers upon them*/ 
        
        .sidebar a:hover { 
            color: #ffffff; 
        } 
        /* Position and style the for cross button */ 
        
        .sidebar .closebtn { 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            right: 25px; 
        } 
        /* Style for the sidebar button */ 
        
        .openbtn { 
            font-size: 25px; 
            background-color: #000000; 
            color: #ffffff; 
            padding: 10px 10px 10px; 
            border: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 12;
        } 
        /* the sidebar button changes 
    color when mouse hovers upon it */ 
.openbtn:hover { 
color: #FFFFFF; 
} 

    /* pushes the page content to the right 
    when you open the side navigation */ 
        
        #main { 
            transition: margin-left .5s; 
            /* If you want a transition effect */ 
            padding: 10px; 
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
×
</a>

<a href="spread.html">Stay Safe</a>
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="#map">Map Beta</a>
<a href="darkmode.html">Dark Mode Lite</a>
<a href="intern.html">NEW! Continents!</a>
<a href="#embeddev">Developer</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">
Links
</button>

</div>
<script> 
    /* Sets the width of the sidebar 
    to 250 and the left margin of the 
    page content to 250 */ 
    function openNav() { 
        document.getElementById( 
        "sidebar").style.width = "250px"; 
        document.getElementById( 
        "main").style.marginLeft = "250px"; 
    } 

    /* Set the width of the sidebar 
    to 0 and the left margin of the 
    page content to 0 */ 
    function closeNav() { 
        document.getElementById( 
        "sidebar").style.width = "0"; 
        document.getElementById( 
        "main").style.marginLeft = "0"; 
    } 
</script>
<div id="header">
<h1 class="qwerty">New Coronavirus Tracker</h1>
<h3 class="qwerty">This Is Where You Can Get All COVID -19 Info
</h3>
<h4>NEW USA Stats at bottom of this page!</h4>
<h3>SHARE THIS PAGE
<a href="linkshare.html" target="_blank" class="oddaout"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/2089/2089782.png" height = 30px></a></h3>
</div><br>


<script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" defer></script>
<div class="elfsight-app-b64cfd63-38a6-4b27-8877-f176e60af02d"></div>

<script src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js" defer></script>
<div class="elfsight-app-eb4a860e-edf5-45a1-9348-f7e008012ac6"></div>
</body>
<br>
<h1>NEW! USA stats</h1>
<iframe src="https://apps.elfsight.com/p/platform.js">
<iframe class="elfsight-app-badbbef6-f719-4652-8b9b-c87b9df7ec1d">
<br>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There are two ways of doing this.**

The first Way to do this is to ad AJAX jQuery and write the max compatibility statement `$(IFRAME-ID).iframe.ms.enter[WEBSITE-URL]`

The other way to di this id to go to a "iFrame to JS" Site. There are lots of these sites all over the internet. Just put in the JS code in the head.

Comment: I used the iFrame to JS because that was more efficient